# Inserting an Opportunity with HasOpportunityLineItem set to true

Tags: apex

I am inserting an Opportunity record, but I need it to have `HasOpportunityLineItem = true` (HasOpportunityLineItem red only filed).

```
Account acc=new Account();
acc.Name = 'TestAccountName';
acc.Industry = 'Automotive';
insert acc;

Opportunity opp=new Opportunity();
opp.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
opp.StageName = 'Identifying';
opp.Type = 'New Business';
opp.Description = 'test desc';
opp.CloseDate = system.today();
opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
opp.Amount = 222;
insert opp;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field `HasOpportunityLineItem` is a standard field, not visible in the UI which is automatically calculated by Salesforce. As the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm) states:

> Read-only field that indicates whether the opportunity has associated
>   line items. A value of true means that Opportunity line items have
>   been created for the opportunity. An opportunity can have opportunity
>   line items only if the opportunity has a price book. The opportunity
>   line items must correspond to PricebookEntry objects that are listed
>   in the opportunity Pricebook2. However, you can insert opportunity
>   line items on an opportunity that does not have an associated
>   Pricebook2. For the first opportunity line item that you insert on an
>   opportunity without a Pricebook2, the API automatically sets the
>   Pricebook2Id field, if the opportunity line item corresponds to a
>   PricebookEntry in an active Pricebook2 that has a CurrencyIsoCode
>   field that matches the CurrencyIsoCode field of the opportunity. If
>   the Pricebook2 is not active or the CurrencyIsoCode fields do not
>   match, then the API returns an error. You can’t update the
>   Pricebook2Id or PricebookId fields if opportunity line items exist on
>   the Opportunity. You must delete the line items before attempting to
>   update the PricebookId field.

Therefore, you cannot set it yourself.

Furthermore, take into account that **when you insert an opportunity and an opportunity line item, in order to have the actual value of `HasOpportunityLineItem` you need to query again the opportunity.** This is because the value gets updated in the server, while your object instance in Apex does not update after an insert.

Run this code in a test or anonymous apex to try:

```
Account acc = new Account(/* Required acc fields */);
insert acc;

Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(/* Required opp fields*/);
insert opp;

OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(/* Required line item fields */);
insert oli;

System.assert(true, [SELECT HasOpportunityLineItem FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: opp.Id].HasOpportunityLineItem );
```

Comment: @ Javier García Manzano thanks for your quick. reply .but i follow the  above rules please check my code

Comment: Hi @srija , you need to edit your question, not post an answer with the code. In any case, I have edited my answer explaining how the system works. I hope it covers what you need.